# One-to-one relation in Shaolinq

Tags: c#, orm

I am using [Shaolinq](https://github.com/tumtumtum/Shaolinq) library for database usage and I have problem with one-to-one relation. I have following database schema:

```
create table A (
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);
create  table B (
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_a_b_id` FOREIGN KEY (`Id`) REFERENCES `A` (`Id`)
);
```

basically those two tables contains info about same things, just different data. That's how someone has designed it, I cannot change it.

However, in the code I would like to have all those data in one object. I have been trying with BackReference, but no luck:

```
[DataAccessObject]
public abstract class A : DataAccessObject<uint>
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PersistedMember]
    public abstract uint Id { get; set; }

    [RelatedDataAccessObjects]
    public abstract RelatedDataAccessObjects<B> Bs { get; }
}

[DataAccessObject]
public abstract class B : DataAccessObject
{
    [BackReference(Name = "", PrefixName = "", SuffixName = "")]
    public abstract A Id { get; set; }

    [PersistedMember]
    public abstract string MoreData { get; set; }
}
```

This created somehow similar schema (obviously Id in B is not primary key now), but after I fill data in DB, Bs property in A is not filled with references. Simply puting abstract property of type B in A also doesn't seem to work since same column is foreign key and primary key at once (Id).

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to access a collection of Bs from As? It seems to me that B is the "super class" that encompasses data from both `A` and `B`. If that's the case, then you can just make `A` the primary key of `B`.

```
[DataAccessObject]
public abstract class A : DataAccessObject<uint>
{
    [PersistedMember(Name = "Id")]
    public abstract override uint Id { get; set; }

    [PersistedMember]
    public abstract string Data { get; set; }
}

[DataAccessObject]
public abstract class B : DataAccessObject<A>
{
    [PersistedMember(Name = "Id", PrefixName = "")]
    public abstract override A Id { get; set; }

    [PersistedMember]
    public abstract string MoreData { get; set; }
}
```

Note that I've overridden the `Id` properties to get the column names matching the SQL. The defaults have meant column names: `AId` and `BId`

Because the primary key is an object it's known in Shaolinq terminology as a "complex primary key". You can use the deflated references feature to retrieve objects just be their primary key without a roundtrip to the database (more here: https://github.com/tumtumtum/Shaolinq/wiki/Deflated-References)

You can query for a specific value of B:

```
// Need to define primary key using an anonymous object because it's not an uint but rather an A that contains an uint.
model.Bs.GetByPrimaryKey(new { Id = 100 } );
```

You can also query for a specific value of B using a deflated reference:

```
model.Bs.GetByPrimaryKey(model.As.GetReference(100));
```

You can also use references within normal LINQ queries:

```
model.Bs.Where(c => c.Id == model.As.GetReference(100) || c.Id == model.As.GetReference(101)).ToList();
```

You can directly access nested/complex primary keys within the query too:

```
model.Bs.Where(c => c.Id.Id == 100 || c.Id.Id == 101).ToList();
```

Note that the above three queries don't need to perform an implicit join be cause the complex primary key is flattened out and stored on the table `B`.

When you get back `B`, you can access `B.Id.Id` without a round-trip query but if you access `B.Id.Data` then that will cause `B.Id` to automatically *inflate* with a hidden round-trip to the database. To avoid this, you can use `Include` to automatically inflate `B.Id` with the first query.

```
model.Bs.Include(c => c.Id).Single(c => c.Id == model.As.GetReference(100));
```

Or more succinctly:

```
model.Bs.Include(c => c.Id).Single(c => c.Id.Id == 100);
```